# Build Array For Search Form Select Option Dropdown

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to create Price Range Filter Dropdown Inside Same Select Options Dropdown
Example:

```html
<select name="price" class="filterSelectBox">
 <option value="disable">Select Price</option>
                    <option value="1">$500-1000</option>
                    <option value="1">$1000-1500</option>
                    <option value="1">$1500-2000</option>
                    <option value="1">$2000-2500</option>
                    <option value="1">$2500-3000</option>
</select>
```

I create php custom array and code like below to get dropdown like above, but i am not getting result like i want, can any one fix this issue for me?
Thanks in advance?
My Idea is to use meta query later in filtering.

```html
<?php
                 $filterPrice = array(
                    array(
                    'maximum_price' => '1000','1500','2000','2500','3000',
                    'minimum_price'=> '500','1000','1500','2000','2500',
                    ));
                ?>
            <li class="filter">
                <span class="selector">
                <select name="price" class="filterSelectBox">
            <option value="disable"><?php _e("Select price","um_lang"); ?></option>
                <?php 
                    foreach($filterPrice as $price):
                ?>
                   
                    <option value="<?php echo $price['minimum_price'].'-'.$price['maximum_price'] ?>"><?php echo $price['minimum_price'].'-'.$price['maximum_price'] ?></option>
                   
                <?php 
               
                endforeach;
                ?>
                </select>  
                </span>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is strange:

```
 $filterPrice = array(
    array(
      'maximum_price' => '1000','1500','2000','2500','3000',
      'minimum_price'=> '500','1000','1500','2000','2500',
  ));
```

Change it to:

```
 $filterPrice = array(
      'maximum_price' => array('1000','1500','2000','2500','3000'),
      'minimum_price' => array('500','1000','1500','2000','2500'),
 );

//.....
foreach($filterPrice['maximum_price'] as $index=>$max_price){
    $min_price = $filterPrice['minimum_price'][$index];
    echo "<option value=".$min_price.'-'.$max_price.">".$min_price.'-'.$max_price."</option>";
}
//....
```

After submitting:

```
//... 
$filter = $_POST['price']; 
list($price_from,$price_to) = explode('-',$filter);
//... using $price_from & $price_to for filtering
//... 
$args = array(
   'meta_query' => array(
        'key'     => 'price', // <- meta_key name for prices
        'value'   => array( $price_from, $price_to ),
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    ),
   // ... others query-params
);  

$q = new WP_Query( $args );
//....
```

Read more about [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: I want to create meta query for wordpress with Minimum and Maximum Price Inside same dropdown instead of creating separated Dropdowns for minimum and maximum Price.
Is there any alternative way to do this?? I want to list Price Range In same select option instead of different dropdowns. I want to get values as $minprice and $maxprice so i can use compare meta query inside theme.

Comment: Do you use `WP`? Ok, make like I have answered ( or @RamRaider). Then use `WP_Query`.

Comment: @Suraz Bhandari Updated

Comment: Thank You !! Perfect It Works Like a Charm :)

Comment: @Suraz Bhandari Ok, greate ^) P.S. Don`t forget to approve answer.

Answer (score 1):

The source array looked peculiar to me but I think this produces a menu as you were wanting.

```
$filterPrice = array(
    'maximum_price' =>  array('1000','1500','2000','2500','3000'),
    'minimum_price' =>  array('500','1000','1500','2000','2500')
);

$maxprices=$filterPrice['maximum_price'];
$minprices=$filterPrice['minimum_price'];

$html=array('<select name="price" class="filterSelectBox">');
foreach( $maxprices as $index => $max ){
    $min = $minprices[ $index ];
    $value = $min . '-' . $max;
    $html[]="<option value='{$value}'>{$value}";
}
$html[]='</select>';


echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
```

If I understand correctly then you would need to javascript to process the selected option in the menu and send an ajax request I think. Though to be honest I'm not entirely sure I understand your exact requirements.

You could assign `dataset` attributes to each option and then use javascript to use those values. For example if you changed the above line to this

```
$html[]="<option value='{$value}' data-min=$min data-max=$max>{$value}";
```

and then added a simple javascript function like this

```
$html[]="
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.querySelectorAll('select[name=\"price\"]')[0].addEventListener('change',function(e){
        var selected=e.target.options[ e.target.options.selectedIndex ];
        console.info( 'use these values for filtering: %s, %s', selected.dataset.min, selected.dataset.max );
    },false);
</script>";
```

The individual min and max are available via the dataset attributes. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: I want to create meta query for wordpress with Minimum and Maximum Price Inside same dropdown instead of creating separated Dropdowns for minimum and maximum Price. Is there any alternative way to do this?? I want to list Price Range In same select option instead of different dropdowns. I want to get values as $minprice and $maxprice so i can use compare meta query inside theme.